# what is the meaning of eval() in x=eval(input("hello"))?

Tags: python, eval

what does `x=eval(input("hello"))` mean, doesn't it suppose to be instead of eval() something like int? I thought of x as a variable that belong to some class that determine its type, does eval include all known classes like int float complex...?

Comment: eval, like the documentation says, evaluates the parameter as if it were python code. It can be anything that is a valid python expression. It can be a function.

Comment: Search protip: "python eval" - first hit was http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval which says "The expression argument is parsed and evaluated as a Python expression.."

Comment: (Also, you're either damn lucky or chose an interesting handle..)

Answer (score 4):

`eval`, like the documentation says, evaluates the parameter as if it were python code. It can be anything that is a valid python expression. It can be a function, a class, a value, a loop, something malicious...

Rule of thumb: Unless there is no other choice, don't use it. If there is no other choice, don't use it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) will interpret the content typed by the user during the `input()`. So if the user type `x+1` with x equals to 1 in locals, it will output `2` (see below).
An extract from the documentation:

> The expression argument is parsed and evaluated as a Python expression (technically speaking, a condition list) using the globals and locals dictionaries as global and local namespace.
>
> ```
> >>> x = 1
> >>> print eval('x+1')
> 2
> ```

It can be dangerous, since the user can type whatever he wants, like... some Unix command. **Don't use it**, unless you know what you are doing (even so, it leads to serious security flaws).

Comment: `eval()` evaluates expressions. `eval("a = 1")` is an error because an assignment is not an expression.